# method returns dynamic type of List

Tags: c#, list, generics

If I have the following:

```
class Super {
 //stuff 
}

class Sub1 : Super {
 //stuff
}

class Sub2 : Super {
 //stuff
}

class Sub3 : Super {
 //stuff
}
```

Run Class

```
class Run {

 //list of type Super with a bunch of sub objects (sub1,sub2,sub3)
 List<Super> superList = sub1,2,3 list;
 List<Super> partialSuperList;

 void doStuff() {
  Type subObjectType = superList[0].GetType();
  if (subObjectType == typeof(sub1)) {
   partialSuperList = categorize(subObjectType);
  } else if (subObjectType == typeof(sub2)) {
   partialSuperList = categorize(subObjectType);
  } else if (subObjectType == typeof(sub3)) {
   partialSuperList = categorize(subObjectType);
  }
 }

 List<Super> categorize(Type type) {
  List<type> subTypeList = new List<type>();
  //loop through subtype list and add it to a super type list
  return SuperList;
 }
}
```

as you can see I'm trying to dynamically create a list with a "type" coming from the argument to the method, am I doing this right or is there another way to do this?

Comment: This sounds as a terrible design...

Comment: @PatrickHofman why is that, I'm trying to avoid repeating 4 lines inside the if/else statements and just calling a 1 line method that does it

Comment: Not everything is meant to be generic, and you really shouldn't create `if` for every type you expect, it's just bad practice.

Comment: what should I use instead of if? I thought of switch but wasn't sure how to do it based on type, please give me advice if you know a better way

Comment: Just make `categorize` as generic method too, as in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
List<T> doStuff<T>() where T : Super
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    // use list
}
```

You don't have the casting problems you have now, and you can check `T` using `is`:

```
if (T is Sub1)
{
    ... // do something
}
```

Comment: but I need a parameter that returns a type so I can create the right type of list- I see, I will try your edit

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: It is possible. See the `List<T>` usage.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to judge if you are doing the right thing since your pseudo code doesn't compile at the moment.

I think you are trying filter a list based on some type. I think the Linq method [`OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) is what you are looking for.

```
var superList = new List<Super> { ... };
var sub1List = superList.OfType<Sub1>().ToList();
var sub2List = superList.OfType<Sub2>().ToList();
var sub3List = superList.OfType<Sub3>().ToList();
```

If you are want to filter on a type you do not know at compile-time, you can do the following:

```
var superList = new List<Super> { ... };
var someType = superList.First().GetType();
var filteredSuperList = superList.Where(x => x.GetType() == someType).ToList();
```

Comment: Won't work since the `type` is dynamic here. It will only work if `type` is an actual type, not a reference to it.

Comment: I can change it so it compiles, give me a minute

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not entirely. If you look at the question the OP is first checking for a specific type using `typeof(Sub1)`, and is than giving that type to the `categorize` method. Why not use it directly as a generic? And aside the title, the word `dynamic` is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: You really think that `superList[0].GetType()` is a good indicator for the type of the list?

Comment: True. Updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: @PatrickHofman just an FYI, for superList[0].GetType() is being used to get the type of Object at that index, and creating the list to to match that type of object

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: I know, and it is horrible. What if there are no items? What type will the list be then?

Comment: @PatrickHofman good point... but this is an MVC application and the link should only show up if the list has objects (if I built it correctly)

Comment: Then use the appropriate methods to do so.